# stuck with error 'notificationHubName' cannot be null. whilst creating Notification hub

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

Trying to create a Notification Hub using the below method. But keep getting the error 'notificationHubName', I've updated the .json file but it still doesn't work.

```
New-AzureRmNotificationHub -Namespace "ContosoNamespace" -ResourceGroup $resGroup -InputFile "C:\Configurations\json.json"
```

Comment: Most likely your json file is missing one of the required parameters..

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know of anywhere that documents the requirements of the .json file?

Comment: Have a look in here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-04-01/Microsoft.NotificationHubs.json

Comment: and here http://wp.sjkp.dk/provision-azure-notification-hub-with-azure-resource-manager-templates/...

Comment: Great! Fixed it.  Thanks for a push in the right direction.